# How to make a button disappear after clicking on it in vf page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, visualforce-component, salesforce-classic

I created a save button in vf page

**VF Code**

```
<apex:page controller="Buffer">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
             <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SaveMethod}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Code**

```
public class Buffer 
{    
     public PageReference SaveMethod()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As soon as I click the Save button, the button must disappear from the Vf page.

Could anyone please let me know how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `rendered` condition for `apex:commandButton`.

**VF page**:

```html
<apex:commandButton rendered="{!NOT(hideSave)}" value="Save" action="{!SaveMethod}"/>
```

**Controller**:

```js
public class Buffer {    
    public Boolean hideSave { get; set; }
    public testController(){
        hideSave = false;
    }
    public PageReference SaveMethod()
    {
        hideSave = true;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to use !NOT in the VF page, instead can't we just put the direct values of True and False in apex code itself. Seems like the validation rules concept...!!

Comment: yes that can also be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript for this:

```
<apex:commandButton 
  value="Save" 
  action="{!SaveMethod}" 
  onclick="this.style.display='none'"/>
```

If you want to reenable the button afterwards, you can do that, too:

```
<apex:commandButton 
  value="Save" 
  action="{!SaveMethod}" 
  onclick="this.style.display='none'"
  oncomplete="this.style.display='inline'" />
```